# how to define rewriterules in cloud9 web-ide

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, cloud9-ide

I'm playing arround with cloud9 and I would like to define rewrite rules for my apache based web application in c9 web-ide. 
I created a .htaccess file (not sure if is located correctly). I guess I need to configure httpd.conf file but can't find such.
how should it be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. Turned out it was all down to typos in the `.htaccess` file. No further configuration was required.

I saved the `.htaccess` file in a folder I created called 'site' which I am using as the root for my web app (so the same folder which contains `index.php`), i.e. like this: `myWorkspaceName/site/.htaccess`

The full contents of my `.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You might copy and paste that to use as a test of the configuration (remembering to save and restart Apache of course).

In case you do need to configure something like `httpd.conf` it appears that you would want to take a look at the following files as a starting point:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/001-cloud9.conf
```

Access to these files is via the command line, so you would type:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/001-cloud9.conf
```

for example.

It may be worth mentioning that for my specific rewrites, the address I would use has to include my sub folder 'site', i.e,

```
https://myWorkspaceName-wkille.c9.io/site/anything
```

whereas

```
https://myWorkspaceName-wkille.c9.io/anything
```

throws a Not Found error.